# How do we get our Journal indexed?

Tags: indexing

We are publishing a Journal titled Chettinad Health City Medical Journal. It is a Quarterly double blind peer reviewed international journal. How do we get it indexed?

Comment: Indexed by what?

Comment: For example, are you trying to get indexed by SCI? SSCI? Scopus? Pubmed? Google Scholar? ... etc. Without knowing these there's no way to answer.